# How can I programmatically copy an incoming VPN connection profile to a Windows 7 computer?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, powershell

In Windows 7, I can create an incoming VPN connection, essentially turning Windows 7 into a VPN server.

Is there any way that I can copy this setup from one Windows 7 PC to another?

For instance, if there was a way I could create the incoming connection via batch, I could distribute the batch file and run it. I'm not aware of the commands to create an incoming connection in batch, however.

Are there any ways this can be done?

[This question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318233/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-windows-vpn-connection) is similar, but this relates to **outgoing** VPN connections. I'm interested in copying **incoming** VPN profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell to create VPN connections and run them using a Batch file.

Here's how to create the batch from a great post on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335004/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-from-a-batch-file)

The Windows PowerShell cmdlet for creating a VPN connection on the client system is Add-VpnConnection.

Syntax

> Add-VpnConnection [-Name]  [-ServerAddress] 
>   [-TunnelType  {Pptp | L2tp | Sstp | Ikev2 | Automatic}]
>   [-EncryptionLevel  {NoEncryption | Optional | Required |
>   Maximum}] [-AuthenticationMethod  {Pap | Chap | MSChapv2 |
>   Eap}] [-SplitTunneling] [-AllUserConnection] [-L2tpPsk ]
>   [-RememberCredential] [-UseWinlogonCredential] [-EapConfigXmlStream
>   ] [-Force] [-PassThru] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm]

Properties

```
Name is the connection name, which is a mandatory parameter, and it cannot be changed.
```

ServerAddress is the IP address (FQDN, or URL) of the remote server to which the connection is to be established. This is a mandatory parameter.

The remainder of the properties are optional. Their names and value sets indicate their purpose. For example, TunnelType specifies the VPN tunnel selection (such as PPTP or L2TP), and AuthenticationMethod specifies the VPN authentication protocol selection.
    Switch parameters (SplitTunneling, AllUserConnection, RememberCredentials, UseWinlogonCredentials), when specified, enable the property.